# prove this theorem about linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $L\colon V \rightarrow W $ is a linear map and $S \subseteq V$ ($S$ is finite), then $L(\langle S\rangle) = \langle L(S)\rangle$.

To avoid confusion, I will drop bracket, such as $L(S)$ to $LS$.

I can show that $\langle LS\rangle \leq  L\langle S\rangle$. (where $A \leq B$ means $A$ is subspace of $B$.)

But I can't prove $L\langle S\rangle  \leq  \langle LS\rangle $  which is opposite relation of what I said above.

Help me to prove the last relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finiteness of $S$ is irrelevant; just remember that only finitely many coefficients in a linear combinations are allowed to be nonzero!
Note that $v\in L(\langle S\rangle)$ is equivalent to $v=L(w)$ where $w$ is a linear compbination of elements of $S$, say $w=\sum c_i s_i$. Then $v=L(w)=\sum c_iL(s_i)$ shows $v\in \langle L(S)\rangle$, hence $L(\langle S\rangle)\subseteq \langle L(S)\rangle$. Of course, on the other hand any $v\in\langle L(S)\rangle$ can be written as linear combination $v=\sum c_iL(s_i)$ of the $L(s_i)$, which  immediately gives us an element $w=\sum c_is_i\in\langle S\rangle$ such that $v=L(w)$, thus showing the direction $\langle L(S)\rangle\subseteq L(\langle S\rangle)$ you already had.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;S=\{s_1,...,s_m\}\;,\;\Bbb F=$ the definition field, then

$$w\in\langle S\rangle \implies w=a_1s_1+\ldots+a_ms_m\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb F\implies$$

$$Lw=a_1Ls_1+\ldots+a_mLs_m\in\langle LS\rangle$$